# Weird situation trying to pushView with an object

Tags: ios, arrays, button, pushviewcontroller, sender

So, here's the deal.
I have 16 buttons in my xib, each is instanced in its controller with the following code:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *left1;
IBOutlet UIButton *left2;
IBOutlet UIButton *left3;
IBOutlet UIButton *left4;
IBOutlet UIButton *left5;
IBOutlet UIButton *left6;
IBOutlet UIButton *left7;
IBOutlet UIButton *left8;
IBOutlet UIButton *right1;
IBOutlet UIButton *right2;
IBOutlet UIButton *right3;
IBOutlet UIButton *right4;
IBOutlet UIButton *right5;
IBOutlet UIButton *right6;
IBOutlet UIButton *right7;
IBOutlet UIButton *right8;
```

When one of those is pressed, it should push a view with an object depending on which button was pressed. Here's how I did that:

```
if (upperLower.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    if (sender == left1) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"11"];
    } else if (sender == left2) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"12"];
    } else if (sender == left3) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"13"];
    } else if (sender == left4) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"14"];
    } else if (sender == left5) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"15"];
    } else if (sender == left6) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"16"];
    } else if (sender == left7) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"17"];
    } else if (sender == left8) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"18"];
    } else if (sender == right1) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"21"];
    } else if (sender == right2) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"22"];
    } else if (sender == right3) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"23"];
    } else if (sender == right4) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"24"];
    } else if (sender == right5) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"25"];
    } else if (sender == right6) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"26"];
    } else if (sender == right7) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"27"];
    } else if (sender == right8) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"28"];
    }
} 
else {
    if (sender == left1) {
        aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"41"];
    } else if (sender == left2) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"42"];
    } else if (sender == left3) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"43"];
    } else if (sender == left4) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"44"];
    } else  if (sender == left5) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"45"];
    } else  if (sender == left6) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"46"];
    } else  if (sender == left7) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"47"];
    } else  if (sender == left8) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"48"];
    } else  if (sender == right1) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"31"];
    } else  if (sender == right2) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"32"];
    } else  if (sender == right3) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"33"];
    } else  if (sender == right4) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"34"];
    } else  if (sender == right5) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"35"];
    } else  if (sender == right6) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"36"];
    } else  if (sender == right7) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"37"];
    } else  if (sender == right8) {
            aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey:@"38"];
    }
}
toothController.aTooth = aTooth;
toothController.aPatient = aPatient;

if (aTooth) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:toothController animated:YES];    
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tooth not found" message:@"The patient doesn't have that tooth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
[aTooth release];
```

Now the problem is I can't figure out why if I press left1, left2 or left3 it works perfectly. Now if I press left4 it crashes, sometimes with an exception (NSCFArray number unrecognized selector sent blalbal) and sometimes without it. All teeth with number 11, 12, 13 and 14 exist in an array. I only tried those since I was too lazy to create 36 of them. But how come it doesnt work only for the number 14?

I've been trying to figure this out for hours unsuccessfully.
Any help apreciated.

UPDATE: (The last update was wrong) I deleted the teeth number 14 from the xml from which the teeth are parsed from and added a tooth number 15. The problem persists with teeth number 15 and show the correct message (tooth doesnt exist) for tooth number 14.

UPDATE 2: I added a "aTooth = nil" after the [aTooth release] and now I can access teeth 15, but I can't access any teeth twice. Once I accessed a tooth, I cant go back there withouth re-compiling.

Comment: How do you populate aPatient.teeth?

Comment: aPatient.teeth is a NSMutableDictionary, each object of that dictionary is a tooth, which has its own class (Tooth)

Comment: oh and every teeth and patient and so on is gotten from a xml. teeth number 14 has the exact same structure as the others though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[aTooth release]` - ??? So you're releasing object after retrieving it from a dictionary?

Comment: im initiating it, settings its values, adding the tooth to the teeth NSMutableArray, releasing aTooth, and all over again for a new tooth

Comment: No. In your code you have `aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectForKey: ...]; toothController.aTooth = aTooth; ... [aTooth release];` So aTooth will be deallocated after first use and array will contain invalid object.

Answer (score 1):

`objectForKey:` is a `NSDictionary` method. You are getting an exception that indicates that `teeth` is a `NSArray`. I believe you want to be using

```
aTooth = [aPatient.teeth objectAtIndex:some-index];
```

Comment: actually teeth is a NSMutableDictionary

Comment: and the exception is only showed after I clean all targets, if I compile a second time after I cleaned all targets it doesnt show the exception, just crashes

Comment: And you verified that `teeth` references a valid `NSMutableDictionary` that hasn't been autoreleased?

Comment: teeth is not set to be autoreleased, but even if it did, how come it works for teeth number 11, 12 and 13 and not 14 ?? 14 is in the same NSMutableDictionary as the others :S

Comment: Good question. Without observing under the debugger, just shooting in the dark based on your description.